# Problem when connecting to Docker hosted postgre db from ASP.Net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-string

The problem I encountered here was with `Host` value in the connection string.

When using `Host=localhost;Port=5432;...` and building the application *over Docker Compose* from Visual Studio the connection fails with the following error:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 'Exception while connecting'
Inner Exception
ExtendedSocketException: Cannot assign requested address [::1]:5432
```

The solution to the problem is to simply use `Host=host.docker.inner;Port=5432;...` instead.

But what I do not get is what is actually wrong here. The database indeed runs on `localhost:5432` which I confirmed by connecting to it using `pgAdmin` tool and this exact address as a server URL. I could access the tables, the data, etc.

So why doesn't the connection from ASP.NET Core work?

Comment: Which `localhost`?  Your outer host system and the application container both independently believe they are `localhost` (as does PostgreSQL, if it's in a container) and those are different `localhost`s.

Comment: And there goes the answer. :) I didn't know that the container running the WebApi thinks of himself as having own `localhost`. I thought that all `localhost`s mentioned in anything Docker-related reffers to the host machines `localhost`.

Comment: So the `Host=host.docker.inner` points to the result of Docker Compose "build" and the connection using this conn-string works because the `host.docker.inner` contains *(exposes)?* collection of all the ports that the containers in the corresponding Docker Compose expose?

Comment: `host.docker.inner` would resolve to "the host machine", what you're describing as "localhost", and it would be able to access any `ports:` that are _published_.  Compose `expose:` doesn't really do anything.  To connect between containers, see also [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation; also [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) discussing `localhost`.